# Cannot scroll in Firefox DevTools' Style Editor using scrollbar thumb

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I have just started using the Firefox Developer Tools. When I am in the *Style Editor*, I can't seem to grab the scrollbar thumb to scroll through my style sheets. I assume I'm missing something but can't find what. I have restarted the developer tools, and restarted Firefox, but that didn't help.

My cursor stays as if it is selecting text, even when I hover over the tiny scrollbar thumb, thus it doesn't let me grab the it. Obviously this is important as style sheets can have many lines!

I am using Firefox 50.1.0 currently.

Comment: Have you tried with [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/), or [Firefox Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org/)?

Comment: Please add a screen capture with a hand-drawn red circle indicating *exactly* what it is that you are attempting to scroll. Also please provide an example URL on which you are trying to scroll. For example, I can scroll the Style Editor on this page just fine in Firefox 50.1.0.

Comment: Have you tried in a stock profile without any add-ons or themes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug filed as [bug 1265807](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1265807) .

A workaround for this is to switch to the Firebug theme, which uses the OS default scrollbars:

[image: Firebug theme]

[image: OS scrollbar in Style Editor using Firebug theme]

Comment: this unfortunately did not help. it's not that i couldn't see the scrollbar - its that as i hover my cursor over it to grab it, and, scroll, it stays as a "text selection" cursor. more importantly, it won't let me grab the bar at all. the problem is not being able to scroll except with up, down, pageup, or page down keys. the cursor not looking as usual but instead as if it was selecting text is not the main issue but seemed relevant.

Comment: i am a bit embarrassed, as restarting my machine fixed this. so i don't know what was causing it, but it's gone.

Comment: Good to know that restarting helped! Though that's a really strange behavior. Anyway, when the bug mentioned in my answer is fixed, this shouldn't be a problem anymore. Also, please note [what to do when someone answers your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).